# How to display version update once user update the app from playstore

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, google-play

Sorry if this is a stupid question since I don't find any solution. So I know that I can get the version number and update-notifier when the update is available on the play store or app store using some flutter package. But I think that I cant show users what the update is about and there is no package like that exists. So I think I need to implement something like an alert dialog manually to show the updated information before I want to publish the update. So, how can I do it with flutter to show that alert dialog just once after the user update the app? Can shared preferences do that? If so how? And is there really a package or ways that I can show the updated information that I don't know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be possible with `package_info_plus` and `shared_preferences`. You can use `package_info_plus` to get the current version and store it with `shared_preferences`. Then on app launch, get the current version from `package_info_plus` and compare it to the stored version.

Here is an example:

```dart
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:package_info_plus/package_info_plus.dart';

bool shouldShowUpdateAlert() async {
  PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String version = packageInfo.version;
  final String? storedVersion = prefs.getString('appVersion');
  await prefs.setString('appVersion', version);
  return version != storedVersion;
}
```

Comment: ahh, that's right.. why didn't think of that... that's the way to know whether it's updated or not... I thought shared preferences won't help since the data will not reset when the app updated but never thought of a trick to use this condition.. thanks mate